# Error rendering a component after Link - React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am facing an error when I am in a component, then I click on the `Link` inside and try to get back.

Basically the flow is: 
`WeddingList` Page **->** Click **->** `Wedding Page` **->** Click **->** `WeddingList`

So, when I click to go back, this error is triggered:

> TypeError: `this.props.weddings.map` is not a function
>   `WeddingList.renderWeddings`

Here is my code:

WeddingList.js

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchWeddings } from '../../actions';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class WeddingList extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchWeddings();
  }

  renderWeddings() {
    return this.props.weddings.map(wedding => {
      return (
        <div className="row" key = { wedding._id }>
        <div className="col s10 offset-s1" key={wedding._id}>
          <div className="card blue-grey darken-1" key={wedding._id}>
            <div className="card-content white-text">
              <span className="card-title">{wedding.coupleName1} & {wedding.coupleName2}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="card-action">
              <Link 
                to={'/wedding/'+wedding.pageName} 
                className="btn">
                Visit!
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      );
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderWeddings()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ weddings }) {
  return { weddings };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchWeddings })(WeddingList);
```

Wedding.js

```html
import React from 'react';
import WeddingPage from './weddings/WeddingPage';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Wedding = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <WeddingPage {...props}/>
      <Link to={'/weddings'} className="btn">Back</Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Wedding;
```

weddingsReducer.js

```html
import { FETCH_WEDDINGS, FETCH_WEDDING } from '../actions/types';

export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_WEDDINGS:
      return action.payload;
    case FETCH_WEDDING:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

reducers.js

```html
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import authReducer from './authReducer';
import weddingsReducer from './weddingsReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  form: reduxForm,
  weddings: weddingsReducer,
  wedding: weddingsReducer
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `this.props.weddings` is `undefined` in the first render. It may happen if weddings are received by ajax request( `fetchWeddings` does it ).  The solution is to set initial state in your reducers.js:

```
import { FETCH_WEDDINGS, FETCH_WEDDING } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = { weddings: [] }

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_WEDDINGS:
      return {...state, weddings: action.payload.weddings};
    case FETCH_WEDDING:
      return {...state, wedding: action.payload.wedding};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Also, you can validate your `PropTypes` in `WeddingList.js`:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class WeddingList extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    wedding:  PropTypes.array.isRequired
  }
  ....
}
```

Comment: The solution with PropTypes did not work.
How do I do with the initialState? I will include my reducers js on the question for you.

Comment: PropTypes verifies your props and logs the error if props is not ok. So you should pass valid weddings anyway

Comment: I am getting the list of wedding in the componentWillMount(). It works when I get into the page or refresh the page. But it is not working when I leave the page and enter again.

Comment: I've edited the answer to match your reducer. Also, check if your fetchWeddings action payload always returns array of weddings or empty array

Comment: Now not even on the first access it is rendering the content. The same error but always now. My fetchweddings action is simple: const weddings = await Wedding.find({});